# Keras in R and prediction on text classification

Tags: r, dataframe, keras, text-classification

I am following the tutorial here (https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorials/beginners/basic-ml/tutorial_basic_text_classification/). Then I like to have predictions on the testing part, so this is the code I've added:

```
# make predictions on testing
predictions <- model %>% predict(testing$text,epochs=20, batch_size=1,   validation_split = 0.1,
verbose = 0)
plot(predictions)
head(testing$text)
predictions
```

What I would like to do now is to convert the numeric values from `predictions` to an actual text form, as "positive" or "negative" values in the example, then merge these values with `testing$text` to yield a dataframe.
Could you please help me figuring it out?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, you could employ the power of `ifelse` function here.

Comment: Thanks @RomanLuštrik, if it's not a problem could you please elaborate it a bit? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
results <- data.frame(
  text=testing$text, 
  class=ifelse(predictions>0.5,'positive','negative')
)
```

Tip: if you're going to use R for ML, you might want to learn the basics of the language.